# Calculating PI with BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal, pi

This is my first time using a BigDecimal and I am having some troubles with it.

Here is my code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal pi = new BigDecimal(4);
        boolean plus = false;
        for (int i = 3; i < 1000000; i += 2) {
            if (plus) {
                pi.add(new BigDecimal(4).divide(new BigDecimal(i), 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
            } else {
                pi.subtract(new BigDecimal(4).divide(new BigDecimal(i), 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
            }
            plus = !plus;
        }
        System.out.println(pi);
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it calculate PI like it should but instead it gives me and answer of 4?

Comment: This is a very slowly convergent series.

Comment: Note that because it is slowly convergent, the results may also appear to have errors.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80 and in particular the "Unusual Behavior" section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never change pi. Remember that BigDecimals are immutable, and you never change yours, i.e., you never assign it to a new value, and so you have to have somewhere

```
pi = ...
```

Inside your if/else would be a good place for this.

```
if (plus) {
    pi = pi.add(new BigDecimal(4).divide(new BigDecimal(i), 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
} else {
    pi = pi.subtract(new BigDecimal(4).divide(new BigDecimal(i), 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
}
```

From the first line from the [BigDecimal API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

> Immutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers.

I would also change that scale of 2 to something better.

Comment: Thank you! But now my code always gives me 3.16 as an answer.

Comment: @ChristopherSmith: you're using a terrible scale value of 2

Comment: Ok, using Integer.MAX_VALUE-1 causes an out of memory exception. Is it safe to allow more memory?

Comment: @ChristopherSmith to what decimal place do you want to calculate pi to?

Comment: @ChristopherSmith: you'll also need to play with your for-loop stop constant.